# Laravel 5.5 como imprimir un objeto en la vista?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

me estoy iniciando en Laravel 5.5, y tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy creando el login de usuarios, al usuario lo logro autenticar, pero cuando lo paso a la vista, no me lo imprime(Error:Undefined variable: users (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_cine\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php))
Intenté pasarlo con la función compact() y with(), pero no me anda. 
Utilicé la función dd() para imprimir el usuario y me funciona. El problema lo tengo en el momento de enviar el objeto a la vista.
Quisiera saber si alguno puede darme alguna sugerencia. Tal vez tenga el error en otro lado.

Clase del Controlador del login:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class ControladorDeLogin extends Controller

{
    protected $guard = 'usuarios';

    public function __contruct(){
        $this->middleware('guest',['only' => 'mostrarFormularioDeLogin']);
    }

    public function login(){

        $credentials = $this->validate(request(),[
            'email' =>'email|required|string',
            'contrasenia' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt(['email'=> $credentials['email'] , 'password' => $credentials['contrasenia'] ] )){
            $users = Auth::getUser();
            //dd($users);
            return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('users',$users);
        }
         //Laravel convierte los arrays en formato JSON
        return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Estas credenciales no coinciden con nuestros registros','contrasenia' => 'No coincide'])
        ->withInput(request(['email']));
    }

    public function mostrarFormularioDeLogin(){
        return view('login');
    }

    public function logout(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }

}
```

La vista del Dashboard (donde irían los datos del usuarios)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('users')
@section('content')
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"> 
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        <h1 class="panel-title">Bienvenido {{$user->email}}</h1>
                    @endforeach
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <strong> Email:</strong>
                </div>


                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-block"> Cerrar sesión</button>
                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

@endsection
```

Controlador del Dashboard

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Usuario;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ControladorDelDashboard extends Controller
{
    public function __contruct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(){
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Ruta declarada en el archivo web.php:

```
Route::get('dashboard','ControladorDelDashboard@index')->name('dashboard');
```

Momento en el que uso la función dd() para imprimir el objeto del usuario
[image: Momento en el que uso la función dd() para imprimir el objeto del usuario]

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres imprimir algún dato del usuario **YA LOGUEADO**, puedes usar esto en tu vista (cualquier vista) mientras ya estés logueado, de lo contrario retornará exception:

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

Puedes cambiar "name" por cualquier campo de tu tabla Users como por ejemplo: email.

Si quieres pasar a la vista un usuario en específico puedes consultar a BD desde tu controller y luego enviarlo a la vista de esta manera:

DashboardController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
   public function __contruct(){
     $this->middleware('auth');
   }

   public function index(){
     $data['usuario'] = User::find(1); //donde 1 es el ID que quieres consultar
     return view('dashboard', $data);
  }
}
```

Y luego puedes imprimir en tu vista "dashboard" de esta forma

```
{{ $usuario->name }}
```

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.